# How do I make Highcharts half-donut appear in angular application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am working on an angular.js application that displays various widgets in a dashboard. One of these widgets uses a Highcharts half-doughnut. I have created a prototype in straight HTML and it works as expected. I am now porting things over to my angular.js application using highcharts-NG. Everything in my widget is displaying EXCEPT the half-doughnut. Here is the code from my partial:

```
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col-md-2 greyBack loanWidget">
        <div class="calendarContainer">
            <div class="calendarTitle">{{myLoan.LoanStatus.Month}}</div>
            <div class="calendarDay">{{myLoan.LoanStatus.Day}}</div>
            <div class="calendarYear">{{myLoan.LoanStatus.Year}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 greyBack loanWidget" style="min-width: 200px; margin: 0; max-width: 200px; max-height: 300px; vertical-align: top;">
        <div ng-controller="LoanStatusChart">
            <highchart id="chart1" config="highchartsNG"></highchart>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--<div id="container" class="col-md-4 greyBack loanWidget" style="min-width: 200px; margin: 0; max-width: 200px; max-height: 300px; vertical-align: top;"></div>-->
    <div class="col-md-3 greyBack loanWidget balance">
        <span class="balanceText">{{myLoan.LoanStatus.OriginalPrincipalBalance}}</span><br />
        <span class="balanceTextLabel">Outstanding Balance</span><br />
        <span class="borrowedText">{{myLoan.LoanStatus.BorrowedAmt}}</span><br />
        <span class="borrowedTextLabel">Borrowed</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 loanWidget"><img src="../images/c4l/cfl-banner.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Here is the code in my controller:

```
cflApp.controller('LoanStatusChart', function ($scope) {

    $scope.options = {
        type: 'pie',
        colors: ['#971a31', '#ffffff']
    }

    $scope.swapChartType = function () {
        if (this.highchartsNG.options.chart.type === 'line') {
            this.highchartsNG.options.chart.type = 'bar'
        } else {
            this.highchartsNG.options.chart.type = 'line'
        }
    }

    $scope.highchartsNG = {
        options: {
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    borderColor: '#000000',
                    size: 115,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        distance: -50,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: 'white',
                            textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black',

                        }

                    },
                    startAngle: -90,
                    endAngle: 90,
                    center: ['30%', '75%']
                }
            },
            colors: ['#971a31', '#ffffff'],
            chart: {
                type: 'pie',
                backgroundColor: '#f1f1f2',
                height: 150
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
        }],
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Hello',
            style: {
                color: '#971a31',
                fontWEight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '15px'
            },
            verticvalAlign: 'middle',
            y: 20,
            x: -24
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Loan',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [
                ['85% paid', 85],
                ['15% owed', 15]

            ]
        }],
        loading: false
    }

});
```

My two questions are:

1. Why won't this display?
2. Currently the data is "hard-coded" in these lines:

   ```
   series: [{
       type: 'pie',
       name: 'Loan',
       innerSize: '50%',
       data: [
           ['85% paid', 85],
           ['15% owed', 15]

       ]
   }],
   ```

How can I set this up so I can pass in the percentages? These come from another controller as you can see in the code in my partial.

**UPDATE:** I have managed to get the chart area to populate with something by adding Jquery prior to the Highcharts.js. However, it is ignoring every single option I pass to it and simply displaying "Chart Title" and a very tall div where the chart should be. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code its running fine. Might be you have some javascript file ordering or CSS issue. Be sure to follow the correct order

- jquery
- Highcharts.js
- AngularJS
- Highchart-ng.js

Secondly you declared `series:[{}]`object twice in your chart configuration.

Here's the fiddle you can check your code here `http://jsfiddle.net/Hjdnw/1018/`

Comment: JQuery was loading after highcharts.js and that was causing this to not render properly. Any idea how to move the chart higher up in the container div?